# Trouble getting footer to stay in the bottom of the page

Tags: footer

I'm using the Twenty ten theme.

I don't know if it matters, but to make the footer stretch all the way out of the page (100%), I put it outside the wrapper div, so instead of:

```
<wrapper>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</wrapper>
```

I've put it this way:

```
<wrapper>
    <main>
    </main>
</wrapper>
    <footer>
    </footer>
```

The css for the footer looks like this:

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    background:#393939;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#777;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
    z-index:999;
    bottom:0;
    clear:both;
}
```

The footer now lays directly under all the content, so if the content of a page is too short, the footer is not in the bottom of the page, like on this page:
http://skiss.nu/hff/?page_id=10

if I add "position: absolute;" the footer stays at the bottom of this page, but it is laying over the content om pages with more content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your position as 'fixed'.

```
#footer {
height: 100px;
background:#393939;
font-size:12px;
color:#777;
margin:0;
padding:20px;
z-index:999;
bottom:0;
clear:both;
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: But if i use "position:fixed" the footer stays in the bottom of the screen and the content scrolls behind the footer.

I want it in the bottom of the page like on this site: http://fridasofia.se/

Comment: ok just re-read your question. you will need to write a jQuery which detects the height of the wrapper, and if it overflows the browser height, apply `'position:fixed'` to the footer, otherwise, `position:static;`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a min-height to your wrapper div like so:

```
wrapper {
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

That won't look awesome on all screen sizes, but its a quick way to get the job done.

Comment: Well, that works, but like you say, it doesn't work so good for different screen resolution...